# Objective C Void Issue - Sending 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'id _Nonnull'

Tags: objective-c

I am receiving the following error:

> Sending 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'id _Nonnull'

for the following line:

```
[comment setObject:[self helloDelegate] forKey:kESActivityToUserKey];
```

Basically I'm using a delegate and the data I am trying to get is an ObjectID in a Parse Class column in which prints to the log fine. So I know that the delegate is working, the issue is that I need this value to save to the Parse Class Column toUser in which Xcode warns me of the error above which prevents me from running the project.

Below is my method I'm calling:

```
-(void)helloDelegate {
    [delegate sayHello:self];
}
```

Next is the method calling the above method:

```
-(void)sayHello:(CaptureManager *)customClass {
    [self.photo objectId];
    // NSLog(@"Object id %@",[self.photo objectId]);
}
```

I am fairly new to Objective C so please understand if I'm not wording things correct. I just need to know how to get rid of the error so I can proceed.

Thank you

Comment: Start with a book about programming on page 1, no matter if it's about Objective-C, C, Java, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`helloDelegate` calls a delegate method but doesn't return anything (aka `void`).

The `setObject:ForKey:` method however expects an object for the `object` parameter.

You need a syntax like this

```
- (NSString *)helloDelegate {
   return [delegate sayHello:self];
}

- (NSString *)sayHello:(CaptureManager *)customClass {

   return [self.photo objectId];
  //NSLog(@"Object id %@",[self.photo objectId]);
}
```